# No scrolling for RecyclerView android Lollipop 5.x

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

Struggling with RecyclerVivew for Android 5.X ( Lollipop ), I have designed simple layout as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1.1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuditStartDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/to" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuditEndDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1.2"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuditDepartmentName"
        style="@style/TextviewPrimaryMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSubItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1.2">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuditSubmitDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.5">

      <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkbAuditStatus"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/check_box"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="end" />
    </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the custom RecyclerView.Adapter is attached to it, with item layout as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout
      android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1.1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuditStartDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/to" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuditEndDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1.2"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuditDepartmentName"
        style="@style/TextviewPrimaryMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSubItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1.2">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuditSubmitDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.5">

      <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkbAuditStatus"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/check_box"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="end" />
    </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now issue with this setup is, the setup is working fine in all the android versions except 5.X as result no scrolling to RecyclerView. Also it is not the only case where no scrolling is observer but the no scrolling is also observed in other Views like Spinner with different observation. In case of Spinners the dropdown List is shown but the selected item is not being reflected on UI.
All the view are inflated within Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by updating the support library to `com.android.support:design:25.2.0`. Also don't know the reason behind this and what exactly does it make difference. If any one have found any reason please let all know. It will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just try to implement this

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4">
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1.1"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAuditStartDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/to" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAuditEndDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1.2"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAuditDepartmentName"
    style="@style/TextviewPrimaryMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="1" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSubItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1.2">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAuditSubmitDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="0.5">

  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkbAuditStatus"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/check_box"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="end" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

 </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it not worked for me and basically I didn't got your point, what it make difference if I add `ScrollView` for the `itemlayout`, can you make it more clear for me?

Comment: For better understanding of your code can you please provide you mail id so that i can see your code on able to provide you better solution